# Adding response to queue if controller fails to reply

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two Microservice based on Spring Boot implementation which interacts using rest calls. Now I want to add failure recovery so that let's for an example

1. Service 1 call service 2 over HTTP
2. Service 1 got crashed die to some error like OOM.
3. Service 2 completed the transaction and now ready to respond back
4. Service 2 tries to respond back but not able to do so as the connection not present.

Now I can implement Spring exception handler but what all exception will be raised in this case. The reason I'm. Confused here is I have seen two Connection Reset (which I think logical) but it also raises sometime HttpMessageNotWritable exception.

If I can handle those exception then I can simply put the response in a queue and Service 1 will pickup the response from queue.

Any help. Would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Well it's very hard to help you as you don't provide any code / reproducible examples. It looks like you're almost asking for architectural advice and at the same time you give some of your errors and in the end you're not really asking any question

Answer (score 0):

You should consider how service1 knows that there are responses waiting for it on service2, and for which request it is a response. Also, if service1 was in a transaction when it crashed, that transaction was not committed. Should it start a new transaction for the service1 part and ask for the queued response of service2?

It would be better to use a REST interface on service2 and ensure that data manipulation operations are idempotent. In that case when service1 recovers it can repeat the call to service2 and a queue is not necessary